# GPPSignIn.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a project in `Xcode` with a `GooglePlus.framework`. I have the `GPPSignIn.h` in this framework inside the folder Headers. But when I want to import it in my `ViewController.h` an error appears. `"GPPSignIn.h file not found"`

A screenshot [here](http://es.tinypic.com/r/30sjarb/8)

Answer (score 4):

If you open "Sample Project" from downloaded sdk archive, and look in AppDelegate, and look closer, you will see, that you must import not from local, but from system.
more simply, you must use:

```
#import <GooglePlus/GPPSignIn.h>
```

instead

```
#import "GPPSignIn.h"
```

p.s. thanks to google doc, make to confuse you.